# UITableViewController inset when UINavigationBar is hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have two `UITableViewControllers`.

One has the navigationbar hidden using the following code

`self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)`

This (obviously) hides the navigationbar. However, it also nicely moves the UITableView inside the UITableViewController to the top of the view.

I'd like to KEEP the UITableView at that nice Y offset (~44pxs) even when the UINavigationBar is hidden.

What is the property that is being updated when I hide the navigationbar? How do I make sure this property stops getting updated when the navigationbar gets hidden?

I've successfully make this stop by adding:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.additionalSafeAreaInsets.top = 44
} else {
    // what do do on iOS10?
}
```

But I don't like this solution because

1. It only works on iOS11
2. It has the 44 magic number being used.

See screenshots below

UITableViewController with the navbar visible
[image: UITableViewController with the navbar visible]

UITableViewController with the navbar hidden
[image: UITableViewController with the navbar hidden]

Comment: Do you use autolayout ?

Comment: I do. In this case, I didn't think I had to, as a UITableViewController is just full screen. It magically gets moved down when the UINavigationBar is visible. I was just curious why/what is happening when that UINavigationBar becomes invisible. Is UIKit adding some constraint for me?

Comment: One way for you to proceed is use autolayout assuming you are using storyboard. ?

Comment: I'm not using a storyboard. I have UITableViewController. I'm just really curious how the UINavigationbar moves that tableview down 44 pixels, but magically moves it back up when the navigation bar is hidden.

What is causing this behavior? What properties are being set? UIEdgeInsets? UISafeArea? Something else?